# Set-AzStorageContainerAcl error due supposed container not found but it really exists

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to update ACL through Azure PowerShell but I'm getting this weird error.
The script is pretty simple but don't understand what is wrong.

1. First I'm getting the Storage Container by name to be sure the
   container already exists.
2. Then just trying to set ACL permission on
   it but got an error saying the container doesn't exist.

Am I missing something?

[image]

**Edit: Just to avoid confusion, I have full control on this storage account resource. I created it and I'm able to configure this setting through Azure portal but no with power shell.**

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Set-AzStorageContainerAcl, I rewrote the script using az cli and worked without problems

Answer (score 0):

1. Browse to Storage Account in the Azure Portal
2. Access Control (IAM)
3. Grant Access to this resource section (Add Role Assignments)
4. Role: Storage Blob Data Contributor
   Assign Access to: Use the default values (I.e. User , Group , or Service Principal)
   Select: User Name
5. Save

Comment: The steps you mention are for very different purpose. My goal is to manage public access for a specific container from a storage account. All this through power shell not from Azure portal.

Comment: @gsubiran these steps are so you are able to access and write the acl from powershell. You need permissions on the object to change ACLs.

Comment: Oh I understand your point but there is no problem with my account permissions over storage account resource. I created the storage account and I'm also able to configure this through Azure portal. The problem is when I'm trying to do this with power shell.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to apply ACL permissions:**

**Here** is the script to apply the **ACL** permission to your **container**.

You can get the **Azure Storage Account Key**

**Azure Portal > Storage accounts > YourStorageAccount >Access keys**

[image]

```
#Install Storage Module

Install-Module Az.Storage

#Connect to Azure AD

Connect-AzureAD

#Set Context to Storage Account
$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'venkatsa' -StorageAccountKey 'StorageAccount-key'

$Container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name 'thejademo' -Context $StorageContext 

#Get Container ACL Permissions

Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Container "thejademo" -Context $StorageContext

#Set ACL permission to Container.

Set-AzStorageContainerAcl -Container "thejademo" -Permission Off -PassThru -Context $StorageContext
```

Applied **ACL** permission to my **container**

[image]

Comment: Hey! There are many ways to get the storage "context" one of them is through storage account name and key. I didn't specify mine in the example but I got the context only through storage account name, cause azure powershell logged in user has enough permissions to alter the resource.